# dpkg configure of util-linux never end, no errors

Tags: apt, dpkg

I ran `apt update` a few days ago, and it never completed. I `ctrl-c` killed it and it said I needed to `dpkg --configure -a`. I did so, and it tries to configure `util-linux`. However, it never finishes. I even let it run for over 12 hours overnight last night, and it doesn't finish. It also doesn't give any error output. It just hangs.

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up util-linux (2.34-0.1ubuntu2.2) ...
```

I tried running it with verbose debugging, but still no useful output that I can see.

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a -D42442
D000040: checking dependencies of util-linux:amd64 (- <none>)
D000400:   checking group ...
D000400:     checking possibility  -> fdisk
D000400:       checking non-provided pkg fdisk:amd64
D000400:       is installed, ok and found
D000400:     found 3
D000400:   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -
D000400:   checking group ...
D000400:     checking possibility  -> login
D000400:       checking non-provided pkg login:amd64
D000400:       is installed, ok and found
D000400:     found 3
D000400:   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -
D000400:   checking group ...
D000400:     checking possibility  -> libaudit1
D000400:       checking non-provided pkg libaudit1:amd64
D000400:       is installed, ok and found
D000400:     found 3
D000400:   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -
D000400:   checking group ...
D000400:     checking possibility  -> libblkid1
D000400:       checking non-provided pkg libblkid1:amd64
D000400:       is installed, ok and found
D000400:     found 3
D000400:   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -
D000400:   checking group ...
D000400:     checking possibility  -> libc6
D000400:       checking non-provided pkg libc6:amd64
D000400:       is installed, ok and found
D000400:     found 3
D000400:   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -
D000400:   checking group ...
D000400:     checking possibility  -> libcap-ng0
D000400:       checking non-provided pkg libcap-ng0:amd64
D000400:       is installed, ok and found
D000400:     found 3
D000400:   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -
D000400:   checking group ...
D000400:     checking possibility  -> libmount1
D000400:       checking non-provided pkg libmount1:amd64
D000400:       is installed, ok and found
D000400:     found 3
D000400:   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -
D000400:   checking group ...
D000400:     checking possibility  -> libpam0g
D000400:       checking non-provided pkg libpam0g:amd64
D000400:       is installed, ok and found
D000400:     found 3
D000400:   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -
D000400:   checking group ...
D000400:     checking possibility  -> libselinux1
D000400:       checking non-provided pkg libselinux1:amd64
D000400:       is installed, ok and found
D000400:     found 3
D000400:   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -
D000400:   checking group ...
D000400:     checking possibility  -> libsmartcols1
D000400:       checking non-provided pkg libsmartcols1:amd64
D000400:       is installed, ok and found
D000400:     found 3
D000400:   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -
D000400:   checking group ...
D000400:     checking possibility  -> libsystemd0
D000400:       checking non-provided pkg libsystemd0:amd64
D000400:       is installed, ok and found
D000400:     found 3
D000400:   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -
D000400:   checking group ...
D000400:     checking possibility  -> libtinfo6
D000400:       checking non-provided pkg libtinfo6:amd64
D000400:       is installed, ok and found
D000400:     found 3
D000400:   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -
D000400:   checking group ...
D000400:     checking possibility  -> libudev1
D000400:       checking non-provided pkg libudev1:amd64
D000400:       is installed, ok and found
D000400:     found 3
D000400:   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -
D000400:   checking group ...
D000400:     checking possibility  -> libuuid1
D000400:       checking non-provided pkg libuuid1:amd64
D000400:       is installed, ok and found
D000400:     found 3
D000400:   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -
D000400:   checking group ...
D000400:     checking possibility  -> zlib1g
D000400:       checking non-provided pkg zlib1g:amd64
D000400:       is installed, ok and found
D000400:     found 3
D000400:   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -
D000040: ok 2 msgs >><<
D000040:     checking Breaks
D000400:       checking breaker login:amd64 virtbroken <none>
D000400:       checking breaker fdisk:amd64 virtbroken <none>
Setting up util-linux (2.34-0.1ubuntu2.2) ...
D000002: fork/exec /var/lib/dpkg/info/util-linux.postinst ( configure 2.34-0.1ubuntu2.1 )
```

It just sits and hangs there.

I can't run any other `apt` commands while the package isn't configured, and I don't want to reboot without a properly, completely installed `util-linux` package.

I have no idea what to do. Any help will be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Debian vanilla, but this same symptom happened to me, and I found a resolution -- I'm posting this answer in case it helps someone get back on their feet from this.

After the hang on util-linux.postinst, I edited the mentioned postinst file to add a crapload of logging:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

LOGFILE=/root/log.file

echo "Environment: " >$LOGFILE
env >>$LOGFILE


echo "update-alternatives" >>$LOGFILE
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/pager pager /bin/more 50 \
    --slave /usr/share/man/man1/pager.1.gz pager.1.gz \
    /usr/share/man/man1/more.1.gz

# We stopped shipping the 'pg' utility, so remove it as a pager
# alternative on upgrades from Stretch.
echo "update-alternatives remove pager" >>$LOGFILE
update-alternatives --remove pager /usr/bin/pg

# Automatically added by dh_installinit/13.1
echo "step 3" >>$LOGFILE
if [ "$1" = "configure" ] || [ "$1" = "abort-upgrade" ] || [ "$1" = "abort-deconfigure" ] || [ "$1" = "abort-remove" ] ; then
    if [ -x "/etc/init.d/hwclock.sh" ]; then
        update-rc.d hwclock.sh defaults >/dev/null || exit 1
    fi
fi
# End automatically added section
# Automatically added by dh_installsystemd/13.1
echo "step 4" >>$LOGFILE
if [ "$1" = "configure" ] || [ "$1" = "abort-upgrade" ] || [ "$1" = "abort-deconfigure" ] || [ "$1" = "abort-remove" ] ; then
    # This will only remove masks created by d-s-h on package removal.
    deb-systemd-helper unmask 'fstrim.timer' >/dev/null || true

    # was-enabled defaults to true, so new installations run enable.
    if deb-systemd-helper --quiet was-enabled 'fstrim.timer'; then
        # Enables the unit on first installation, creates new
        # symlinks on upgrades if the unit file has changed.
        deb-systemd-helper enable 'fstrim.timer' >/dev/null || true
    else
        # Update the statefile to add new symlinks (if any), which need to be
        # cleaned up on purge. Also remove old symlinks.
        deb-systemd-helper update-state 'fstrim.timer' >/dev/null || true
    fi
fi
# End automatically added section
# Automatically added by dh_installsystemd/13.1
echo "step 5" >>$LOGFILE
if [ "$1" = "configure" ] || [ "$1" = "abort-upgrade" ] || [ "$1" = "abort-deconfigure" ] || [ "$1" = "abort-remove" ] ; then

echo "step 5.1" >>$LOGFILE
    if [ -d /run/systemd/system ]; then
echo "step 5.2" >>$LOGFILE
        systemctl --system daemon-reload >/dev/null || true
echo "step 5.3" >>$LOGFILE
        if [ -n "$2" ]; then
echo "step 5.4" >>$LOGFILE
            _dh_action=restart
        else
echo "step 5.5" >>$LOGFILE
            _dh_action=start
        fi
echo "step 5.6" >>$LOGFILE
        deb-systemd-invoke $_dh_action 'fstrim.timer' >/dev/null || true
echo "step 5.7" >>$LOGFILE
    fi
echo "step 5.8" >>$LOGFILE
fi
# End automatically added section
# Automatically added by dh_installsystemd/13.1
echo "step 6" >>$LOGFILE
if [ "$1" = "configure" ] || [ "$1" = "abort-upgrade" ] || [ "$1" = "abort-deconfigure" ] || [ "$1" = "abort-remove" ] ; then
    if [ -d /run/systemd/system ]; then
        systemctl --system daemon-reload >/dev/null || true
        if [ -n "$2" ]; then
            _dh_action=restart
        else
            _dh_action=start
        fi
        deb-systemd-invoke $_dh_action 'fstrim.service' >/dev/null || true
    fi
fi
# End automatically added section
echo "step 7" >>$LOGFILE
```

Examining the output in /root/log.file, I found step 5.6 was the blocker. Manually running the systemctl commands there also caused a hang. A quick google suggested the system would run fine without fstrim (for awhile - this has disk longevity issues, especially for SSDs), so I commented out all of the fstrim commands, and re-ran `dpkg --configure util-linux` successfully.

Hope it helps!